# Schedule exporting an output to a csv file to local folder or sharedrive

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a scheduled task run in Snowflake every month and dump the result to a view table called "ABC".

I run the view on the first day of every month, and manually export output to a CSV or TXT file in my local folder.

Now, I want to automate export. So every month, I want Snowflake automatically export the view ABC to my local drive. And this is where I stuck. Please advise.

Comment: You would need to copy the data to an internal stage (which you could schedule using a task) but to then get the data to a local file system would require you to run a GET command - run via SnowSQL or a driver - and would need to be scheduled outside of Snowflake

Comment: If instead of moving the file you could have Snowflake send you an email with a link to the file, that would have zero external dependencies. You'd need a simple stored procedure that copies the view to a file and then calls the `BUILD_STAGE_FILE_URL` function. You can take the resulting hyperlink and send it to your email using `SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL()`. The advantage to this approach is that it has zero external dependencies to manage or break. The downside is, it's not exactly what you're asking for - that the file arrives on your local drive automatically.